# Skin Modifier and hole in mesh during applying sculpt brushes

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I used skin modifier and used subdivision surface modifier and made the following shape.

[image]

Then I came to sculpt mode and started to use clay brush. Then while applying clay brush around the neck (the place I marked in blue) I got a hole.

To fix that I returned to object mode -> edit mode and selected the edges and used F key to make a face and apparently the hole gone. I returned to sculpt mode and while applying the clay brush the same thing happened. I got a hole.

How to fix this issue?

EDIT: A few more screenshots as asked in comments.

[image]

[image]

Selected the edges and pressed F key -

[image]

Going back to sculpt mode

[image]

Now I noticed that whenever I am using clay brush in dyntopo mode either at that place or in other place holes are being created. What could be the reason and how to fix them?

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: @MrZak Yes I used mirror modifier. Well I thought I would be using sculpt, and hence I didn't try to remove doubles. But what causes that?

Comment: @MrZak I tried with removing doubles and the fixing the holes in edit mode. But when I am sculpting again holes are coming in other places.

Comment: If you had a solid mesh (or at least you intended it to be solid), and while sculpting some holes started appearing underneath your brush the mesh has unclosed areas (non-manifold geometry, possible to select with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+M), which are not visible from beginning due to faces overlaying on top of each other and hence I called as double vertces above. That's all what's clear from the description. There are 2 overlapping areas (left one and right) below the neck, mesh is non-manifold likely. You can share it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com if you want somone check it

Comment: @MrZak i will upload my .blend file. But what is the password there?

Comment: @MrZak I have added the blend file. Please tell how to remove them.

Comment: The mesh is made from quite wrong topology which will perfectly prevent from any further editing, it has [overlapping faces, inner faces which somehow are formed with rolled structure of the body](https://imgur.com/a/uN1DhWh). Taking into account basic forms of the mesh my advise would be to start over and sculpt the same body with dyntopo from a cube.

Comment: @MrZak I already started doing it from the start. But can't we remove overlapping faces from that mesh? Any shortcut? Or option?

Comment: It *is* possible to fix, though due to multiple self-intersections in the mesh and overlapping faces it'll be just a waste of time as the mesh is not that complex to preserve it. The toolset is the same - Select Non-Manifold, Remove Doubles, Alt+M to join vertices

Comment: @MrZak but that will be manual operation? Working on each points one by one?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55333/39647 I found here some info as well. Have ro try it.

Comment: Yes, those errors in geometry neither fall under Remove Doubles operator, nor can be removed with something like Remesh modifier etc. so if fixing then manual way is likely needed. Some overlapping faces can be removed there with X > Delete Face, maybe Ctrl+F > Intersect could be useful as well somehow.